# view search queries by popuarity containing keyword

Tags: search-engine

I have been spending some time watching the search queries that bring people to my site on google analytics recently, in order to see if people are finding exacty what they are looking for and if not creating that new content. But i figured an easier way would be to what search queries are popular. But containing a keyword that relates to my site.

for example, i want to see all the most queried search terms that contain "in japanese".
like "dog in japanese", "i love you in japanese"

I have found http://www.google.com/trends/

but after playing with it for a while it doesnt seem like i can do this. seems like i can just see popularity of spesific queries. I dont want to see how popular specific queries are, i want to see what queries containing x are popular. Anywhere i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you join the Google AdWords program, you can use the Keyword Planner tool to try out keywords and immediately get the number of searches per month in a chosen geography. This is a very interesting tool. See http://adwords.google.com.

I'm not sure this question belongs here on SO though.